# Is there a way to access to a non-root-class from another secondary class?

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

Actually, I have 2 similar questions:

1. Is possible to access to class FaceNameTxtIn, capturing the text of the TextInput, from class TrainerBtn not using global variables (for example, through ids, self.parent... I've tried without success)?
2. How can I access to trained_faces_value.text of TrainerBoxLayout from the function on_release of TrainerBtn? The procedure from the root class is:

   self.root.ids.TrainerBoxLayout.ids.trained_faces_value.text

   and the program runs properly and so I've changed self.root in self.parent (and then self.parent.parent) but the process fails and returns
   'Process finished with exit code 1'.

(I've already searched a lot online without finding a solution that matches with my problem)

**FaceRec.py**

Kivy libraries

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.settings import SettingsWithSidebar
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.actionbar import ActionBar
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.core.window import Window
```

HomeScreen classes

```
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class HomeActionBar(ActionBar):
    pass

class TitleLabel(Label):
    pass

class StatusBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class ErrorsBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TrainerBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TrainerBtn(Button):
    def on_release(self):
        global face_name
        face_name = face_name.replace(' ','')
        ...

class FaceNameTxtIn(TextInput):
    def on_text(self,instance,value):
        global face_name
        face_name = value

class RecognizerBtn(Button):
    def on_release(self):
        ...
```

Main class

```
class FaceRecApp(App):
    ...

    def build(self):
        self.root = HomeScreen()
        Logger.info('FaceRec.py: FaceRec.kv loaded')

        self.settings_cls = MySettingsWithSidebar
        Logger.info('FaceRec.py: MySettingsWithSidebar loaded')

        ...

        return self.root

    ...
```

Sidebar settings

```
class MySettingsWithSidebar(SettingsWithSidebar):
    ...
```

Execute

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    FaceRecApp().run()
```

**FaceRec.kv**

```
#: import WipeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.WipeTransition

<ScreenManagement>:
    transition: WipeTransition()
    HomeScreen:

<HomeActionBar>:
    id: HomeActionBar
    background_color: 0.9,0.9,0.9,0.5
    pos_hint: {'top':1}
    size_hint_x: 1
    ActionView:
        use_separator: True
        ActionPrevious:
            title: 'Home'
            with_previous: False
        ActionOverflow:
        ActionButton:
            text: 'Logs'
            on_release:

        ActionButton:
            text: 'Settings'
            icon: 'settings.png'
            background_down: 'settings.png'
            on_release:
                app.open_settings()

<TitleLabel>:
    id: TitleLabel
    text: '[b]FaceRec[/b] - [i]The Face Recognition Project[/i]'
    color: 0.0,0.3,1,1
    markup: True
    font_size: 45

<StatusBoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        id: status
        text: 'Status: '
    Label:
        id: status_value
        text: 'Error'
        color: 1,0,0,1

<ErrorsBoxLayout>:
    id: ErrorsBoxLayout
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        id: errors
        text: 'Errors No: '
    Label:
        id: errors_value
        text: '...'

<TrainerBoxLayout>:
    id: TrainerBoxLayout
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        id: trained_faces
        text: 'Trained faces: '
    Label:
        id: trained_faces_value
        text: '...'

<TrainerBtn>:
    id: TrainerBtn
    text: 'Press to run the Face Trainer'
    font_size: 25
    size_hint: 0.5,1.4

<FaceNameTxtIn>:
    id: FaceNameTxtIn
    hint_text: 'Insert your name and then press the button below'
    font_size: 19
    size_hint: 0.5,1.4
    multiline: False

<RecognizerBtn>:
    id: RecognizerBtn
    text: 'Press to run the Face Recognizer'
    font_size: 25
    size_hint: 0.5,1.4

<HomeScreen>:
    id: HomeScreen
    name: 'HomeScreen'
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'face_pointed.png'

    HomeActionBar:
        id: HomeActionBar

        BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 70
        TitleLabel:
            id: TitleLabel

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: 20

            StatusBoxLayout:
                id: StatusBoxLayout
            ErrorsBoxLayout:
                id: ErrorsBoxLayout
            TrainerBoxLayout:
                id: TrainerBoxLayout

            FaceNameTxtIn:
                id: FaceNameTxtIn

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'

                TrainerBtn:
                    id: TrainerBtn
                RecognizerBtn:
                    id: RecognizerBtn

            Label:
                text: 'Press q to quit the video'
                font_size: 20
```

**Thank you for the precious support**.

Comment: You might have better luck getting a fast answer if you boil your example down to your problem. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Kivy there are different possibilities to access other classes.

- **self** ... is the widget itself
- **app**  ... is the Application
- **root** ... is the Root of the current class
- **app.root** ... is the root of the app

You can also use parent and children to access classes, which is mostly a bad idea, because you have to adapt the path every time you change the structure.

In general the classes much know from each other, this is done by using Kivy properties.

As you see in this example it is important, that you define the properties in the context you want to use. The Root is often a good place.

The following example demonstrates how to use Properties to manipulate data withing the kv file and python.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

Builder.load_string('''
<MyLabel1>:
    text:"label 1"

<MyLabel2>
    text:"label 2"

<AppRoot>:
    lbl_1:lbl_1
    lbl_2:lbl_2
    btn_1:btn_1 
    MyLabel1:
        id: lbl_1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text:"ignore this"
                MyLabel2: 
                    id:lbl_2
    Button:
        id:btn_1
        on_press: 
            root.lbl_2.text = root.lbl_1.text
            root.do_something_in_root()
            app.do_something_in_app()
''')

class MyLabel1(Label):
    pass

class MyLabel2(Label):
    pass

class AppRoot(BoxLayout):
    def do_something_in_root(self):
        print("AppRoot {}".format(self.lbl_1.text))
        self.lbl_2.text="set in AppRoot"

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AppRoot()
    def do_something_in_app(self):
        print("App {}".format(self.root.lbl_2.text))
        self.root.lbl_1.text="set in APP"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

In your case you could use the following methods (all implemented in the code below):

- directly from the KV File
- in the root of the which is HomeScreen
- in the app

  :

  ```
  FaceNameTxtIn:FaceNameTxtIn
  TrainerBtn:TrainerBtn
  id: HomeScreen
  name: 'HomeScreen'
  canvas.before:
      Rectangle:
          pos: self.pos
          size: self.size
          source: 'face_pointed.png'

  HomeActionBar:
      id: HomeActionBar

      BoxLayout:
      orientation: 'vertical'
      spacing: 70
      TitleLabel:
          id: TitleLabel

      BoxLayout:
          orientation: 'vertical'
          spacing: 20

          StatusBoxLayout:
              id: StatusBoxLayout
          ErrorsBoxLayout:
              id: ErrorsBoxLayout
          TrainerBoxLayout:
              id: TrainerBoxLayout

          FaceNameTxtIn:
              id: FaceNameTxtIn
              text:root.TrainerBtn.txt

          BoxLayout:
              orientation: 'horizontal'

              TrainerBtn:
                  id: TrainerBtn
                  on_press:
                      root.FaceNameTxtIn.text="on press from TrainerBtn"
                      root.on_press_from_btn()
                      app.on_press_from_bnt2()

              RecognizerBtn:
                  id: RecognizerBtn

          Label:
              text: 'Press q to quit the video'
              font_size: 20
  ```

  In the Py File:

  ```
  class HomeScreen(Screen):
      def __init__(self, **kwargs):
          super(HomeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

      def on_press_from_btn(self):
          print("some button was pressed")
          # the property is defined in the kv
          self.FaceNameTxtIn.text="value changed from method in app"

  class FaceRecApp(App):
      def on_press_from_bnt2(self):
          print("on press executed in app");
          app = App.get_running_app()
          app.root.FaceNameTxtIn.text="value changed from method in app"
  ```

Comment: And... How can I use app.root in Python? From TrainerBtn (FaceRec.kv) I can write on_release: app.root.ids.TrainerBoxLayout.ids.trained_faces_value.text = '1', but how I should do to write the same thing in Python?

Comment: using this would be possible, but very troublesome, as you would have to rewrite it, every time you change the layout structure. The best way is to use Objectproperties as described in the answer above.

Comment: @A.B. you could use `App.get_running_app().root.ids`